# rake db:create will giving me the error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

hi friends here is some problem when i'm doing rake db:create
i'm getting errors like this

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: railtie_name is deprecated and has no effect. (called from <class:Engine> at /home/shajin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bundler/gems/spree_paypal_express-073f2f814dd8/lib/spree_paypal_express.rb:5)
WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  Please use 'require 'rdoc/task' (in RDoc 2.4.2+)' instead.
    at /home/shajin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb
WARNING: Global access to Rake DSL methods is deprecated.  Please include
    ...  Rake::DSL into classes and modules which use the Rake DSL methods.
WARNING: DSL method Soletronspree::Application#task called at /home/shajin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize_tasks'
WARNING: 'task :t, arg, :needs => [deps]' is deprecated.  Please use 'task :t, [args] => [deps]' instead.
    at /home/shajin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/deface-0.5.2a/tasks/deface.rake:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
rake aborted!
!!! Missing the mysql2 gem. Add it to your Gemfile: gem 'mysql2'

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: It gives the fix to each of the problems its detecting; have you tried to follow that?

Answer (score 0):

You've specified in your `config/database.yml` file that you're connecting to a DB using the MySQL adapter, but you're not including the `mysql2` gem in your Gemfile, and/or the gem is not otherwise installed in your app.

Toward the bottom of your error message it says:

```
!!! Missing the mysql2 gem. Add it to your Gemfile: gem 'mysql2'
```

That's your problem.

Comment: ya changed after that also same error
and in that
 !!! Missing the mysql2 gem. Add it to your Gemfile: gem 'mysql2'
removed.

Comment: So, you added `mysql2` gem, and still got *exactly* the same error?

Comment: i've changed in gem file gem 'mysql', and in the database.yml file i've changed adapter mysql

mysql2 error is removed now, but  other error remains as it is .

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using? 2.3.x? 3.1.x? 3.2.x? edge rails?

Comment: It still looks like it's a `database.yml` config/format issue. See: https://github.com/rbjarnason/open-active-democracy/issues/1  Can you post your `database.yml` file (with your DB username/password **removed**, of course) so I can see if there are any obvious formatting issues/typos that might be causing the problem?